# Add styles to bootstrap forms

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

I have selection form on Bootstrap, I need to add styles and make it like on this image below. Please check below `html` and `css` for this image form:

[image]

`form html on image:`

```
<form method="POST" action="/identify">  
  <div class="wrap">
     <div class="search">
        <input type="text" id="value"  multiple="multiple" class="searchTerm" name="value" placeholder="Type your values">
        <datalist id="val">
            <option value="val">val</option>
        </datalist>
        <button type="submit" class="searchButton" name=form>
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
     </div>
  </div><br>
</form>
```

`form css on image:`

```
.search {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.searchTerm {
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #00B4CC;
  border-right: none;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: none;
  color: #9DBFAF;
}

.searchTerm:focus{
  color: #00B4CC;
}

.searchButton {
  width: 60px;
  height: 66px;
  border: 1px solid #00B4CC;
  background: #00B4CC;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.wrap{
  display: none;
  width: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  
}
```

`my bootstrap selection form code:`

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

      <section>
        <div class="container h-100">
  <div class="wrap">
     <div class="search">
          <form action="/action" method="POST" class="form-inline">
            <select id='sel' name='sel' class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
              <option value="value">value</option>
              <option value="value">value</option>
              <option value="value">value</option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Select</button>
          </form>
</div>
</div>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            $('select').selectpicker();
          </script>
        </div>
      </section>
```

I have added styles for the form on the image. But how to make it to my `select form`?

Comment: Please show us also your css of what you have tried

Comment: @Sfili_81, I have added all code. Please check it again.

Comment: I don't understand. If you want to copy-paste the style of some other element, you would have all the code relevant to what you want by simply inspecting the element and copy paste those CSS properties into your own CSS.

Comment: @Martin, the deal is that I tried to copy-paste, but not working. Could you show it, please

Comment: I wouldn't know, I don't have the element to inspect. I wouldn't know where to find it. All you need is to target your appropriate element through a slector of your choice, either `class`or `id` with the CSS properties that you find from inspecting the element.

Comment: It sounds like you are having a caching problem. Try to visit the page in private mode via the browser and see if the changes are applied. If that is the case, then you only have to clear the cache. [Shortcuts firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Keyboard+shortcuts) search for: Reload (override cache

Comment: @Fredrik, I have changed code, but when run it on localhost changes not come into force, and I see previous version of code. I cleared cache, but it did not help.

Comment: Are you sure you are importing the css you did update? In the code above you are importing from the internet.

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />

Comment: @Fredrik, yes, it works. I have still the problem which I mentioned in the question. Could you please clarify how can I changed the width and height of `selection` tag?

Comment: share your problem on stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

All you must do is delete everything in between the `<div>` tags which are right inside you `<section>` tags. I believe it should look like this.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
 <section>
        <div class="container h-100">
  <div class="wrap">
     <div class="search">
          <form action="/action" method="POST" class="form-inline">
            <select id='sel' name='sel' class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
              <option value="value">value</option>
              <option value="value">value</option>
              <option value="value">value</option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Select</button>
          </form>
</div>
</div>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            $('select').selectpicker();
          </script>
        </div>
      </section>
        </div>
      </section>
```